# I want to animate this layout when the radio button clicked. But it isn't working

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to animate this layout when the radio button clicked. But it isn't working

This is my layout
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqtEw.png)

State change listner for radio button

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if (checkedId == R.id.radio_button_login){
                    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(LoginActivity.this,R.anim.bottom_up);
                    signUpLayout.setAnimation(animation);
                    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            signUpLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });

                }else {
                    Log.e("TAG", "onCheckedChanged: "+checkedId +"  :  "+ R.id.radio_button_login );
                    signUpLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        });
```

But the animation is only starting when i clicked the Edittext in the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:duration="200">
<scale android:fromXScale="100%" android:toXScale="100%" android:fromYScale="100%" android:toYScale="0%"/>
</set>
```

This is my animation resource

Comment: You didn't start animation . You must start animation.

Comment: But the animation is starting when i clicked on the edit text in the layout. And "signUpLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)" this method starts animation for ither views